# Best way to download xml as Inputstream from an URL

Tags: android

MY code is as below for downloading the xml content from as url, This is taking more time to download in wifi network , My xml is just 29.2kb. Im using AsyncTask to this.

```
InputStream getInputStreamForUrl(String url) {
        BufferedHttpEntity bufferedEntity = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            bufferedEntity = download(url);
            if (bufferedEntity != null) {
                is = bufferedEntity.getContent();
                if (is != null) {
                    BufferedReader feedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Utility.UTF_ENCODING),
                            16 * 1024);
                    Utility.cacheFeed(feedReader, url);
                }
            }
        } catch (NetworkNotAccessable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (bufferedEntity != null) {
                    bufferedEntity.consumeContent();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return (url != null) ? Utility.getInputStreamForCache(url) : null;
    }
```

The download(url) method Im using HttpGet request as below:

```
public BufferedHttpEntity download(String url)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, 
                    IllegalStateException, NetworkNotAccessable {
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = mDefaultHttpClient.execute(get);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (status != 200) {
            throw new NetworkNotAccessable(url + "error code:" + status);
        }   
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();           
        BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);      

        while (bufHttpEntity.isStreaming()) {
            try {
                bufHttpEntity.wait(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return bufHttpEntity;
    }
```

Please let me know is there any best way to zip the whole url and download it.

Comment: Please place the code for Utility.cacheFeed and Utility.getInputStreamForCache(url)

Comment: if you're able to change the server code then [gzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) the xml response, and on your client side use [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html).this is how i minimize the time on my downloads.

Comment: @user_CC Utility.cacheFeed and Utility.getInputStreamForCache(url) are the methods used to cache the Bufferreader with url as the key and fetch the InputStream by providing the url. I'll Just update the local chche after downloading the Inputstream . download(String url) is the method where the download is exactly happening.

Comment: @Adi did you manage to resolve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are saying that actual download is happening in 'download(url)' method then I am afraid I can't see that happening, also download method is called from getInputStream method which you are returning the inputstream can't see any reason for that...

Also why are you using bufHttpEntity.wait(500); this is a blocking state (Can cause major delays)

use the following code in your download method to retreive the xml:

```
    URL url = new URL(url);
       HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       try {
         InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
         byte buffer[] = new byte[4096];

         int count;
         String xmlData = "";
         while( (count = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
           xmlData += new String(buffer, 0, count);
       } finally {
         urlConnection.disconnect();
       }


             Log.d(TAG, " Data: " + xmlData );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It helped me to reduce the download time